# Updating just one option with update_option

Tags: options

There are many options within an 'option' in the 'wp_options' table. This option, `second_option`, contains three parameters and consequently has three values. The values are, for example, as follows:

```
{s:12:"manual";s:0:""; s:8:"currency";s:3:"USD";s:14:"state";s:2:"nn";}
```

I want to update the value of the second parameter, and that is `'currency'`, yet whenever I want to update just this portion, Wordpress just updates whole of the option and the first option and the third, that is `'manual'` and `'state'` are deleted and just remains what I am updating, that is `'currency'`. I use the following piece of code:

```
$sets = get_option( 'second_option' );
$sets['currency'] = 'some_value';
update_option('second_option', $sets);
```

Is there a way to update just the option `'currency'` without affecting other parameters, that is `'manual'` and `'state'`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is correct, but the problem is that the value inside the option in your example, i.e.:

`get_option( 'second_option' );`

is not serialized correctly ( it was either edited directly--and incorrectly--through the database or inserted with something other than `update_option()` ).

If you `var_dump( get_option( 'second_option' ) );`, you'll see that it's not an array but a string.

The correct serialized value in the database for your example would be:

a:3:{s:6:"manual";s:0:"";s:8:"currency";s:3:"USD";s:5:"state";s:2:"nn";}

Using that, your approach will work as expected. However, instead of editing this manually (as it is prone to errors, like in this example), just do a reset of the option like so:

```
$second_option = array(
  'manual'   => '',
  'currency  => 'USD',
  'state'    => 'nn',
);
update_option( 'second_option', $second_option );
```

Afterwards, this will work as expected:

```
$sets = get_option( 'second_option' );
$sets['currency'] = 'some_value';
update_option( 'second_option', $sets );
```

PS: There is no need to unserialize or serialize when using get_option() and update_option() respectively, these functions take care of that.